# Как отключить вывод в консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я собираю .py в .exe приложение с интерфейсом (PyQt)
И когда я использую:

```
os.system('wmic process where name="python.exe" CALL setpriority "realtime"')
```

На мгновение появляется командная строка, которая сбивает все полноэкранные приложения (Сворачивает их)

Мне нужно как - то отключить вывод в консоль.

Вывод в консоль будет как при успешном выполнение команды, так и наоборот. Поэтому не важно имя процесса `name="python.exe"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть пара вариантов:

1. В pyinstaller добавить флаг `--noconsole`
2. Второе ваша команда `wmic ...` может принудительно отрисовывать консоль. перенаправьте вывод например в текстовый файл `wmic ... > myfile.txt`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что даже если нет консоли, при вызове этой команды оно появляется на мгновение во время выполнения.

А вот 2 способ работает, но можно перенаправлять его в "Пустоту"? Просто не хочется что бы создавался не нужный файл.

Comment: С ходу не припомню таких вариантов. Но можно сделать в скрипте удаление файла.